# What is this device administrator called screen lock service?

Tags: security, settings, device-administrator

I was looking at the device administrators of my phone in the settings and saw a device administrator called "screen lock service". It's description is "Activating this administrator will allow the app Google play services to perform the following operations: set password rules". I have looked at my device administrators before and this particular one was never there before. It just appeared out of nowhere. Can anyone tell me what this is and if I should be doing something about it?

Comment: Are you using a Motorola device? Some moto device users seems to have come across this new device admin as well. See https://www.google.com/search?q=%22screen+lock+service%22+&oe=utf-8

Comment: A bunch of other people have had this administrator pop up and they asked on forums but no one knew why it suddenly popped up. I was hoping someone here would know

Comment: Can you setup [tag:adb] in your PC and then provide the output of this command: `adb shell dumpsys package  resolvers | sed -n '/android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED/,/:/p'` // Use a paste code service such as pastebin.com to provide the dump/output.