# Screen Lock Service as a Device Administrator

Tags: security, device-administrator

Background:

> I was looking at the device administrators of my phone in the settings and saw a device administrator called "screen lock service". It's description is "Activating this administrator will allow the app Google play services to perform the following operations: set password rules".

A previously unsettled question is found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/229222/332973).

I searched the net for the apk file of the application but could not find one. So as per suggestions, I ran

```
adb shell dumpsys package  resolvers | sed -n /android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED/,/:/p
```

The output for the above code was:

```
  android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED:
    438a74 com.motorola.demo/.admin.DemoModeAdminReceiver
    2acd3de com.google.android.gms/.auth.managed.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver
    36b5d24 ch.deletescape.lawnchair.ci/ch.deletescape.lawnchair.gestures.handlers.SleepMethodDeviceAdmin$SleepDeviceAdmin
    42aae3e com.google.android.gms/.tapandpay.admin.TpDeviceAdminReceiver
    8efd08d com.google.android.gms/.kids.account.receiver.ProfileOwnerReceiver
    9b4f242 com.google.android.gms/.mdm.receivers.MdmDeviceAdminReceiver
    a9980b6 com.oasisfeng.greenify/.DeviceAdmin
    b5771b7 com.google.android.gm/com.android.email.SecurityPolicy$PolicyAdmin
  com.motorola.internal.intent.action.INETCONDITION_REPORT:
```

The data for the code is quite unsettling for the fact that none seem to correspond to *screen lock service*.

For reference, I am using Moto G5 Plus (not rooted, stock build with no customizations)

Also note that, I own another **same** device which is rooted and runs Pixel-Experience (Android 10 latest build) and unfortunately it does not have the *Screen Lock Service*.

An insight/breakdown for this application is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

> The data for the code is quite unsettling for the fact that none seem to correspond to screen lock service.

I can see why it confused you, believing that there would be an app or a service running with the same name on the system which you would have been able to identify quite easily, but could not.

The device administrator "Screen Lock Service" **is a device administration service** offered by **Google Play Services** (*com.google.android.gms*) app.

This is how I approached the problem:

1. I searched for a device with this problem. I managed to get my hands on a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 running Android 9 having this administrator service enabled.
2. I went ahead with disabling Screen Lock Service administrator. Side by side, I had `logcat` running to *grep* any entry beginning with "admin".
3. Through logcat I got the following output on disabling the said administrator.

   ```
   Device admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.managed.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver} removed from user 0
   ```
4. `com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.managed.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver` is one among the many device administrators mentioned in the output of the command `adb shell dumpsys package  resolvers | sed -n /android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED/,/:/p` and is also mentioned in your output.
5. I decided to verify further by pulling the apk of Google Play Services and decompiling it. In the decompiled AndroidManifest.xml file, the relevant entry for this device administrator was this:

   ```
   <receiver android:description="@string/auth_device_admin_receiver_description" android:enabled="false" android:exported="true" android:icon="@drawable/product_logo_security_shield_color_24" android:label="@string/auth_device_admin_receiver_label" android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.managed.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" android:process="@string/common_persistent_process" chimera:autoEnabled="false">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@xml/auth_password_complexity_device_admin"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED"/>
            </intent-filter>
   ```
6. I used the information in step 6 to get three things:

   - the label of the device administrator in `res/values/string.xml`:

     ```
     <string name="auth_device_admin_receiver_label">Screen lock service</string>
     ```
   - the description of the device administrator in `res/values/string.xml`:

     ```
     <string name="auth_device_admin_receiver_description">"<b>Allow apps to determine the quality of the device's screen lock</b>"</string>
     ```
   - the icon for the device administrator in `res/drawable-xhdpi/product_logo_security_shield_color_24.png`:

     [image]
7. As for disabling it. While you can disable it, a reboot re-enables it automatically without user intervention. It appears to me that `com.google.android.gms.persistent` process is responsible for this. Not only is that process mentioned in the Manifest, but also during logcat it was the one after which auto-enabling of Screen Lock Service took place. Relevant logcat of post boot process:

   ```
    [ 10-01 19:59:17.126  3058: 7809 W/.gms.persisten ]
    Long monitor contention with owner lowpool[10] (7811) at void java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(java.lang.Object)(FinalizerReference.java:56) waiters=0 in java.util.Map bggj.a() for 980ms   

   [ 10-01 19:59:17.163  3441: 7374 I/Auth     ]
   [AuthManaged, PasswordComplexityHelperImpl] Updating password complexity components state.

   [ 10-01 19:59:17.163  3441: 7374 I/Auth     ]
   [AuthManaged, PasswordComplexityHelperImpl] Enabling com.google.android.gms.auth.managed.ui.SetNewPasswordActivity

   [ 10-01 19:59:17.164  3441: 7374 I/Auth     ]
   [AuthManaged, PasswordComplexityHelperImpl] Enabling com.google.android.gms.auth.managed.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver
   ```

---

## Summary

1. Screen Lock Service is a device administrator feature of Google Play Services app
2. If you disable it, Google Play Services app would re-enable it without seeking your authentication.
3. Its purpose is not documented on Google Support / Answers as of now.

Comment: (+1) Good answer and conclusions. Further questions to answer: You mentioned that you pulled the apk of Google Play services. Is the apk from the same device, or is it pulled from an online resource such as apkmirror etc. ? If it is pulled from an online resource, it seems that the service should be provided on all devices....but it isn't the case (Any reasons/speculations why?). And finally, is the Redmi Note 5 from Asia-Pacific region (A question which may inspect whether the service is region specific)

Comment: 1.) Didn't get a +1 yet. Haha. 2) APK from the same device. 3) Yes, from Indian region.  4) I don't know why only some devices have this problem. More so, it is prevalent more in Moto devices, per basic search results from web.

Comment: you'll probably be able to see my +1 on SEDE after a week, but by then i may be able to upvote :P I will most probably award the bounty here (so that makes +10)... can we break down the service (lock screen service) further? or maybe just tell how I can see the break down of that specific service? (what the answer provided is that the admin enabled application/service is implemented by Google Inc, but i want to dissect the service itself

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Sorry. No updates on it.

Comment: I think this is now documented officially at https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/managed/password/PasswordComplexityServiceClient